# Getting the exponent from a floating point in C

Tags: c, floating-point, numbers, exponent

I'm writing a function that will get the exponent of a floating point number (IEEE 754 standard) but for some reason when I use the right shift bitwise operator on the number it returns 0

Here is the function

```
int get_exp (int x) 
{
  return ( ((x >> 21) & 255) -127 ); 
}
```

I'm passing it 7.23 so the output should be 2, for some reason the (x >> 21) part returns 0 when it should actually be returning 129. The 255 is the mask I'm using to and (&) with the exponent part of the floating point number.

Comment: Post code example of "I'm passing it 7.23"

Comment: Why is the right shift in the code above by `21` instead of by `23` bits?

Answer (score 9):

I'm guessing you're doing some kind of casting hocus-pocus to pass floating point as `int`s? I would use `float frexpf (float x, int* exp);` as defined in `<math.h>`.

```
#include <math.h>

int get_exp(float x) 
{
    int exp;
    frexpf(x, &exp);
    return exp; 
}
```

It's guaranteed to work regardless of the sizes of the floating point types.

If you want to roll it yourself, you can adapt this code.

```
#define EXPONENT_BIAS (-127)

int get_exp(float f) 
{
    int i;
    union {
        // Set here, then use s or c to extract
        float f;
        // This may or may not work for you
        struct {
            unsigned int sign: 1;
            unsigned int exponent: 8;
            unsigned int mantissa: 23;
        } s;
        // For debugging purposes
        unsigned char c[sizeof(float)];
    } u;

    // Assign, you might need to reverse the bytes!
    u.f = f;

    // You'll probably need this to figure out the field widths
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(float); i++)
        fprintf(stderr, "%02x%s", u.c[i], (i + 1 < sizeof(float))? " ": "\n");

    // Just return the exponent
    return (int)u.s.exponent + EXPONENT_BIAS;
}
```

This will bite you if `sizeof(float) != 4`, or if you switch endian-ness.

Comment: I have to do it without using any defined functions

Comment: @Yimin Rong is there a way to do it without frexp?

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof(float)==4,"Implementation error!");`

Comment: Note: These 2 methods (both correct) have an off-by-one difference due to the different ideas of significand/mantissa range.

Answer (score 2):

Working under the assumption that a `float` is 32 bit and is laid out [as specified here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), you have three issues:

- Your function needs to accept a `float`.
- You need to point a `uint32_t` to the address of the `float` so it sees the same bytes, then perform actions against the dereferenced pointer.
- The exponent starts at the 24th (23 if you start from 0) bit, not the 22nd (21 if you start with 0), so you have to shift by 23.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int get_exp (float x)
{
  uint32_t *i = (uint32_t *)&x;
  return ( ((*i >> 23) & 255) -127 );
}

int main()
{
    printf("exp=%d\n",get_exp(7.23));
}
```

Result:

```
exp=2
```

Comment: @KareemYoussef It cannot, otherwise the number in question won't be in  IEE 754 floating point format.  Not unless you construct it manually from an array of bytes, that is.

Answer (score 2):

Main issue is the passing of `int` rather than `float` and using 21 vs 23. [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32659588/2410359)

IEEE 754 standard (binary32) has a number of corner cases: Inifinty, NaN, sub-normal including zero.  So additional code is needed to cope with them.

Assuming proper endian:

```
int get_exp(float x) {
  assert(sizeof x == sizeof(uint32_t));
  union {
    float x;
    uint32_t u32;
  } u = { x };
  #define EXPOSHIFT 23
  #define EXPOMASK 255
  #define EXPOBIAS 127
  if (x == 0.0) return 0;
  int expo = (int) (u.u32 >> EXPOSHIFT) & EXPOMASK;
  if (expo == EXPOMASK) return INT_MAX;  //  x is infinity or NaN
  if (expo == 0) return get_exp(x * (1L << EXPOSHIFT)) - EXPOSHIFT;
  return expo - EXPOBIAS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should performance not be an issue, simply iterate:

```
int expof(float f) {
  int expo = 0;
  if (f < 0.0) f = -f;
  while (f < 0.5f) {
    f *= 2.0f;
    expo--;
  }
  while (f >= 1.0f) {
    f *= 0.5f;
    expo++;
  }
  return expo;
}
```

Does not depend on any particular `float` implementation other than the exponent fits in `int`.  It use no external functions as commented  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659336/getting-the-exponent-from-a-floating-point-in-c/32660097#comment53165130_32659379).

Same result as from `int expo; frexpf(f, &expo); return expo`

Comment: This should be the correct answer!

Answer (score -1):

The parameter list show

```
int x
```

and you pass a floating point number. Try to substitute with

```
float x
```